# Is there any way to configure view controller element from the cell custom class

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a custom class called "customerInformationTableViewCell". I have a textfield in this cell to which I have connected it as an outlet. I have a view controller which contains a list. I want to modify this list when the text field's text changes. How can I do it ? pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. You can create protocol `NamedCellDelegate`

```
protocol NamedCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func anyFunc(parameters: Any) /*With needed parameters*/
}
```

### 2. do following in Cell

```
weak var delegate: NamedCellDelegate?
```

Then on text's editing changed add action from Sent Event section and in handler method call `delegate?.anyFunc(parameters: Any)`

3. in viewController's `cellForRow` after creating cell set `cell.delegate = self`

### 4. extend `UIViewController` and implement method

```
extension UIVIewController: NamedCellDelegate {
    func anyFunc(parameters: Any) {
        // change list
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude !